# Need a bat script to rename a file based on date while doing ftp

Tags: datetime, ftp, batch-file, filenames, rename

Here is my situation.

I have a server which is saving file everyday in the following format:
TACO_2012-Dec-30__21-50-00_UTC.csv

I want to rename this file to following format using bat script:
TACO_20121230_215000.csv
TACO_yyyymmdd_hhmmss.csv

Here is what I want to do as a script
1. Login to ftp server
2. rename file to the new format as above

Please help...

Comment: The thing is I am new to bat scripting... So don't know which functions to use... The main problem is how to get the name of the remote file that is to be renamed as each file has a different name.. As I will be using this batch script to run automatically everyday after the report on the sever has been created

Comment: You haven't even made your question clear. Is the file to be renamed on the remote machine? If so, you can't use a batch file; you'll need to use ftp commands. If it's on the local machine, why do you need batch commands to rename it (you can do it when it's downloaded)? And searches of this site (and others via Google and Bing) should give you a starting point if it's necessary to use a batch file. Posting zero efforts to solve it yourself isn't an actual attempt. This isn't a "write my code for me" site. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=_.-" %%A in ('dir /B TACO_*') do (
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  call :getmonth %%B
  ren TACO*_*%%A-%%B-%%C*_*%%D-%%E-%%F_UTC.csv TACO_%%A!mon!%%C_%%D%%E%%F.csv
  endlocal
)


:getmonth
if "%1" equ "Jan" set mon=01
if "%1" equ "Feb" set mon=02
if "%1" equ "Mar" set mon=03
if "%1" equ "Apr" set mon=04
if "%1" equ "May" set mon=05
if "%1" equ "Jun" set mon=06
if "%1" equ "Jul" set mon=07
if "%1" equ "Aug" set mon=08
if "%1" equ "Sep" set mon=09
if "%1" equ "Oct" set mon=10
if "%1" equ "Nov" set mon=11
if "%1" equ "Dec" set mon=12
goto :eof
endlocal
```

Comment: thanks for this command but some reason i cant get this to work....the  filename doesnt changes

Comment: fixed. Didn't pay attention that your file has two underscores.

Comment: This is working perfectly fine.. How can I add the following before executing this:
FTP
open 10.195.2.2 (FTP.server)
ftp-user (Username)
ftpuser (Password)
cd reports/AASummary

After this I will run the above script... Please Help
I have tried to put the above FTP commands in a Bat file but when i run it it gets stuck on FTP>

Comment: At the moment I have not enough time to offer you a refined FTP script .You can check this page at first http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsFtpBatchScript.php .As this is a different question may be it will be better to ask another question here.B.R.